# Term for "over stimulation"

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

I'm looking for a certain word, usually being said about the current generation,
something like *attention deficit caused by over stimulation* (like people don't want to wait for more than 30 seconds for a video, etc).

**Update:**
The word I was looking for was desensitized

Answer (score 1):

*Restive* comes to mind: Unable to keep still or silent and becoming increasingly difficult to control.

Comment: mm.. not exactly, I'm looking for something to do with the attention, or lack of it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps *fractious* would be what you are looking for. See meaning (2) [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fractious), or perhaps the other synonyms offered (particularly *testy* and *captious*).

Answer (score 1):

The words you could use to describe the current generation:

1. restless
2. speeded-up
3. impatient
4. high-strung
5. on-edge

These are simple terms that you have probably thought of yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind a bit of slang, how about *wired*?

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wired